# ReadAsStringAsync and its imports

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two projects, both .NET Framework 4.7.2.

In both projects, my `Imports` statements are the same.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Net.Http
```

The older project recognizes `HttpClient` but the newer project doesn't...

```
Public Async Function getQueryURL(url As String) As Threading.Tasks.Task
  Dim hc As HttpClient
  hc = New HttpClient
  Dim strServerInfo As String = ""
  Dim result As String = ""

  Dim rm As HttpResponseMessage()
  rm = Await hc.GetAsync(url)

  If rm.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
    Dim res As String
    res = Await rm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

    result = res
  End If
End Function
```

The broken project wanna import (quick-refaktor)

```
Imports Windows.Web.Http
```

Comment: Are you using 'PackageReference' on the project that has the error? Are you using the NuGet package for your `HttpClient`? If so, build the project to pull in the reference.

Comment: i think thats the error i check it :-)

Comment: Same name, but very different classes.  The UWP flavor requires a Uri argument, string cannot work.  Simply use `new Uri(url)` to fix the problem.

Comment: can't really see a difference... @nuGet both have only JSON support. but how could i tell that i wanna use Imports System.Net.Http for "HttpClient"?

Comment: ok i get it... i had to reference to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll then it works... it does not work automatically

Answer (score -2):

To forbid to imports this

```
Imports Windows.Web.Http
```

i had to reference in the project to the path of System.Net.Http

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll then it works... it does not work automatically
```

then the project uses the right extended version von Windows.Web.Http

```
Imports Windows.Net.Http
```